# How can I deep-link to a project (and sprint) within VersionOne

Tags: versionone

Does anyone know of a way to "deep-link" to a storyboard for a specific project that you currently don't have selected?

I have tried stuff like this:

```
/VersionOne/Default.aspx?menu=StoryBoardPage&feat-nav=m1&scopeId=Scope%3A1015534

/VersionOne/Default.aspx?menu=StoryBoardPage&feat-nav=m1&projectId=Scope%3A1015534

/VersionOne/Default.aspx?menu=StoryBoardPage&feat-nav=m1&project=Scope%3A1015534
```

but it doesn't change the project.

I'd like to create a perma-link to the storyboard, so having a sprint/iteration param would be helpful too

```
/VersionOne/Default.aspx?menu=StoryBoardPage&feat-nav=m1&scopeId=Scope%3A1015534&timeboxId=TimeBox%3A1024555
```

This might not be possible but I wanted to see if anyone had found a hack.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  You can do direct links to assets (story, defect, etc) but you can't specify a context in-line to a board, or backlog.  At least not as of this posting.